# HTML Input tag, with type file, in some cases doesn't catch "oninput " event

Tags: javascript, html

So, in my file upload page, I have a file dragging and dropping area. By clicking on this area, the file input dialog appears to allow the user to select files. In some random cases after selecting the files and clicked Open, the **oninput** event is not emitted. Am I doing something wrong?

I tried to change the **oninput** event to **onchange**. And it's not working to. Has  anyone had  this problem? Thanks in advance.

```
let input = document.createElement("input");
input.type = "file";
input.style.cssText = "display:none;";
input.multiple = true;
input.accept = "." + this.options.allowedFileType;
input.oninput = () => {
Array.from(input.files).forEach(file => {
      if (file.type === "application/pdf") {
        self.setUniqueUuidAndStoreFile(file);
      } else {
        self.displayErrorNotification(
        this.$t("file") + " " + file.name + " " + this.$t("wrongFileType")
      );
    }
  });
};
input.ondrop = function (event) {
  return false;
};
input.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is "normal" system doesnt register the change from time to time, because it doesnt see the whole file, for security reasons. The workaround we are using is seting the value on click to null

```
input.onclick = function () {
    this.value = null;
};
```